# Can't tap from one TextInput to another

Tags: ios, react-native

When I'm focused in one `TextInput`, tapping in another `TextInput` field doesn't do what I'd expect (change **focus** to that `TextInput`).

Instead, it simply **blurs** the current `TextInput`, requiring a **second tap to focus** the next `TextInput`.

Is there some way to do this, or is this a current shortcoming of **React Native**?

Example code:

```
class MyTest extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <View>
          <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
          <TextInput style={styles.textInput} />
        </View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#ddd',
    paddingTop: 64
  },
  textInput: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    borderColor: '#000',
    borderWidth: 1,
    height: 46,
    paddingLeft: 10
  }
});
```

Turns out, when the input fields are within a ScrollView, they behave as I described above (you can't just tap from one field to the other). I tried wrapping the TextInputs in a View to remedy this, but it didn't work.

Comment: Could you include some relative code in your post?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` to you [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).

> **keyboardShouldPersistTaps bool:**
>
> *When false, tapping outside of the focused text input when the keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When true, the scroll view will
>   not catch taps, and the keyboard will not dismiss automatically. The
>   default value is false.*

Comment: This is now updated, so, use 'always', of the 3 new possible values ("always" | "never" | "handled"), as described in: https://reactnative.dev/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps

Answer (score -1):

You Can Use Resign First Responder using TextInput Delegate Method