# React Native on android - focus from one TextInput to another TextInput needs 2 taps

Tags: android, react-native

it is really annoying, when I write text in one TextInput, then I tap on another TextInput to get focus with keyboard ready and it only hides the keyboard. How to overcome this behavior? All I want is to tap on TextInput and to have keyboard ready immediately.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are your TextInputs in a ScrollView?

You need to add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps={true}` to you [ScrollView](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html).

> **keyboardShouldPersistTaps bool:**
>
> *When false, tapping outside of the focused text input when the keyboard is up dismisses the keyboard. When true, the scroll view will
>   not catch taps, and the keyboard will not dismiss automatically. The
>   default value is false.*

See [Can't tap from one TextInput to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354099/cant-tap-from-one-textinput-to-another).