# Tapping from one TextInput to another in ScrollView should not dismiss the keyboard

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a ScrollView to TextInput controls.

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container}>
    <TextInput style={styles.input}/>
    <TextInput style={styles.input}/>
</ScrollView>
```

On Clicking the TextInput, the keyboard appears as expected. If I click outside the TextInput in the View area, the keyboard should disappear as it happens now. In addition, I click on another TextInput, the keyboard should remain on the screen. It requires two clicks or taps when moving from one TextInput to another on the screen.

This is similar to another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35354099/cant-tap-from-one-textinput-to-another). When I implement the answer in the question, the keyboard does not disappear when tapping on the ScrollView.

The RNPlay can be found [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/HfXoDg).

Comment: They added some keyboard events in v0.27. Check it out and it might help you: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.27.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using `keyboardShouldPersistTaps` on `ScrollView`should remove the dismiss behaviour when clicking on other `TextInput`

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.container} 
            keyboardShouldPersistTaps ={true}>
  <TextInput style={styles.input}/>
  <TextInput style={styles.input}/>
</ScrollView>
```

But it disable the keyboard dismissal behaviour when clicking outside the `TextInput`

Consider adding a click listener on `ScrollView` and when click detected hide the keyboard using [react-native-dismiss-keyboard](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dismiss-keyboard) module

Comment: thankyou for telling to use react-native-dismiss-keyboard